# How to add Java EE Servlet API library on your compile classpath in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ and I have been working on a few small projects to familiarize myself with IDE and how to develop Java web projects with it.

I recently picked up Professional Java for Web Applications to practise my web development skills and I wanted to try it because it focuses on IntelliJ rather than Eclipse.

My main issues are from not knowing my way around the IDE at all. I have come across a problem that I have been unable to figure out how to do correctly.

How do you add Java EE Servlet API library on your compile classpath ?
Where is the compile classpath located in IntelliJ ?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It seems Intellij does not have a good documentation..M I wrong?? ;)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you are managing dependencies in your project.

If you are using Maven simply add it as a dependency in your pom.xml. When IDEA sees a maven based project it will over for you to Import Changes and/or Enable Auto Import. A common JavaEE 7 maven dependency would look like this in your pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you are only using an IDEA project to manage things (vs. maven, gradle etc.) then you can go into the project structure dialog, click on modules and select the module containing your web tier code. Then click on the dependencies tab. Then click on plus button (+) and add a JAR, then navigate to the JAR containing the servelet APIs that is bundled with your application server and select that.

There are another half dozen ways to set this up and exactly which one you choose depends on a lot of factors like how you want to manage provided dependencies in your project etc. Either of these methods should get you on your way though.